# private method with springmvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have two methods in my controller:

1. a public method
2. a private method

They all have `@requestMapping` and they all quotes a global variable(`@autowrite`). The problem is that the first method the variable has value and the second method variable is null.

Please help me.

```
    /** 
      * Both of these methods are accessible through the browser, 
      * when i ask for query1 the flowService has value but  
      * when i ask for query2 the flowService is null. 
      * My spring version is 4.2.4 
      * Created by hanxiaofei on 2017/10/12. 
      */
   public class TestController {    
       @Autowired    
       private FlowService flowService;  

       @RequestMapping(value = {"/query1"})    
       @ResponseBody    
       public CommonListResult<WorkOrderMO> query1() {
        return flowService.queryWorkOrderList(1);    
       } 

       @RequestMapping(value = {"/query2"})
       @ResponseBody
    private CommonListResult<WorkOrderMO> query2() {
        return flowService.queryWorkOrderList(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is quite hard to help you unless you post sample code which shows the problem you are facing.

Comment: Show us some code pls.

Comment: you could post your code and show us at which line you are getting null

Comment: Thanks for you all, i had put on some code.

Answer (score 2):

Controller methods annotated with `@RequestMappings` must be public in order to work correctly. There is no reason to make request methods as private anyway as you are not supposed to call controller methods by yourself from different components anyway.

Comment: Thank you,but i cant ask for a private method though browser just like my code show.

Comment: Method will be called indeed, but on special proxy that has no @Autowired field in it, thus your results. The same will apply for example to private methods annotated with `@ModelAttribute`. `@RequestMapping` methods are to be public.

Comment: So the cause  of the different is java not spring,i know spring can ignore private but i can't understand why it's null when i ask for query2 method,they all use flowservice attribute and the attribute belong to same container.I know i should use public key word,but i want to know why it is null under legitimate circumstances.

Comment: @韩晓飞 Im not Spring expert and I dont know the internals so that kind of detail leves is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you Antoniossss^_^

Comment: The fact that you are not supposed to call these methods is precisely a good reason to mark them as private, don't you think?

Comment: yes, and it would be beneficial if it would work, but it does not. For the matter code correctness you want to have such methods private, but in this case by default all controller methods should be "kind of a private" and never be called. This is what I had in mind. You are making the public but never call them by yourself thus private/public will make no difference (besides obvious lack of help of compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Again If you don't want to call it then what is the advantage in declaring it, You can't call it from any other class due to private nature and also controller methods not meant to be called from other classes and you don't want to call it from the browser because you will not be able to.

So how are you testing that `flowService` is null in `query2` method because you will not be calling it from anywhere?

However, your problem has nothing to deal with this private and public controller method, it is something else because `flowService` is an instance variable and if `query1` method is able to able to access it then `query2` should do it as well.

Comment: Thank you for answer,but i want to know why flowservice is null when i ask for query2 though brower.The only difference is that query1 use pulic and query2 use private.Can you explain some of the details?

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC controllers works with any scope: `public`, `private`, `protected` or package-private access modifier.

You can validate it with this sample controller that works fine:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private FlowService flowService;

    @RequestMapping("/query1")
    public List<String> query1() {
        return flowService.queryWorkOrderList(1);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/query2")
    private List<String> query2() {
        return flowService.queryWorkOrderList(2);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/query3")
    protected List<String> query3() {
        return flowService.queryWorkOrderList(3);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/query4")
    List<String> query4() {
        return flowService.queryWorkOrderList(4);
    }
}
```

I have tested it with Spring Framework `4.3.11.RELEASE` so the first thing to try for your issue it to use the latest version available.

That's said, I don't see why somebody would like to use `private` controller methods. `public` is most frequently used but specifying no scope is shorter and produce the same result (`query4()` in my example).

Comment: Thank you deleuze,Yes, the private method works fine, but the global variable referenced in the private method is empty.Like flowservice in my code.

Comment: I have updated my example, and reference to `flowService` is fine as expected. Please provide a repro project if you still see the issue.