# AutoWired JPA Repository is null in some method of controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPARepository like this

```
@Repository
public interface RestaurantRepo extends JpaRepository<Restaurant, String> {
    Optional<Restaurant> findByName(String name);

    Optional<List<Restaurant>> findAllByMerchantId(String merchantId);
}
```

I then have a controller where I am initializing the Repository like this

```
@Autowired
RestaurantRepo restaurantRepo;
```

Then I have one method where I am using the Repository like this

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("/disable")
    public ResponseEntity<CustomResponse> disableUser(String username, boolean disable) {

        Restaurant restaurant = restaurantRepo.findById(username).get();
        restaurant.setDisabled(disable);

        CustomResponse er = new CustomResponse();
        er.setStatus("Successful");
        if (disable) {
            er.setMessage("Restaurant is disabled");
        } else {
            er.setMessage("Restaurant is enabled");
        }
        restaurantRepo.save(restaurant);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(er, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Whenever I hit this api, it works fine.
Then I have another method like this

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN','ROLE_RESTAURANT')")
    @GetMapping("/get")
    private ResponseEntity<Restaurant> getRestaurant(Principal principal) {
        String username = principal.getName();
        System.out.println("username "+username); //prints the valid username
        System.out.println("RestRepo "+restaurantRepo); //prints null
        Restaurant restaurant;
        Optional<Restaurant> opt = restaurantRepo.findById(username); //prints Exception here
        if (opt.isPresent()) {
            restaurant = opt.get();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(restaurant, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            restaurant = new Restaurant();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(restaurant, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }
```

Here I get a NullPointerException in this line `Optional<Restaurant> opt = restaurantRepo.findById(username);`

The username is a valid username, and so when I print the `restaurantRepo` I get `null`.

I am confused as to why the variable is not null in one method while it is null in another method. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are the methods disableUser and getRestaurant in the same controller?

Comment: @Niyas yes, they are in the same controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure. But try to change the access modifier in the second method to **public**.
Please refer this  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684838/private-method-with-springmvc)

Also use constructor injection instead of @Autowired annotation.